# Why does min attribute cause ngChange to be called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following input field:

```
<input type="number" 
    class="menu-control validate" 
    style="width: 50px;" 
    ng-disabled="!ctrl.editable()" 
    min="1" 
    ng-change="ctrl.updateBookingPriceRequest()" 
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 2000, 'blur': 0 }}" 
    ng-model="extra.quantity" />
```

My problem is the min directive. While it's there, angular starts repeatedly calling ng-change without the input having changed at all (not good since I'm performing an ajax call on change). If I remove min it works just fine, and I don't have the same problem with max.
It doesn't seem to matter if the model is above or below min initially.

Can anyone see something that I can't?

Edit:

I tried making my change function do nothing, and it stopped the problem, so it must be due to my code. But what I don't understand is why it works fine without min!

```
this.updateBookingPriceRequest = function () {
            _this.prices.getBookingPrice(_this.bookingPrice).then(function (response) {
                if (response.successful) {
                    _this.bookingPrice = response.data;
                    _this.bookingPrice.mooringExtras.bookingExtras.forEach(function (extra) {
                        var feature = _this.features.filter(function (f) { return f.featureId === extra.mooringFeatureId; })[0];
                        extra.unitOfMeasureId = feature.unitOfMeasureId;
                        extra.pricedQty = feature.pricedQuantity;
                        extra.pricingType = feature.pricingType;
                    });
                    if (_this.bookingPrice.mooringDiscounts) {
                        _this.bookingPrice.mooringDiscounts.forEach(function (discount) {
                            discount.discountName = _this.harborDiscounts.filter(function (x) { return x.id === discount.discountModelId; })[0].name;
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                    _this.Error.showErrorMessage('Error getting booking price: ' + response.message);
            });
        };
```

The "extra" object on which the model is a property is changed in the function, however the "quantity" property remains the same. Could this cause ng-change to be triggered?

Edit to show how objects are defined (see comment by valepu):

The extra object(s) are in an array (my input field is inside a repeater, but in my current test there is only one object in the array), which is defined on a property called mooringExtras, which in turn is a property of a bookingPrice object, which is updated via an http request when ng-change gets called (see code). I know it gets complicated, my apologies for not knowing how to simplify it better.

The extra object contains a number of properties, with "quantity", a number, being the model for the input.

Here is an JSON of the extra object:

```
{"id":401,"bookableFeatureId":13,"mooringFeatureId":4,"featureName":"Wi-fi","bookingId":1104,"booked":true,"price":100.00,"totalAmount":300.00,"days":8,"quantity":3,"currencyUnit":"SEK","created":1460542055177}
```

Every time ng-change is called the bookingPrice object is changed, however, the value of extra.quantity remains the same.

Comment: I guess Angular is doing his cycle when having a `min` attribute. A cycle usually means that Angular detects a change and then it fires the `change` function. Can you reproduce in a fiddle maybe?

Comment: your min is a directive ?

Comment: i have made a plunkr that should emulate your situation but it works fine to me (on Firefox) http://plnkr.co/edit/XyEyGTvuYKyz1GGmWjuP?p=preview (also min is standard HTML, not an angular directive, unless you have a directive with such a name)

Comment: @valepu Thanks for pointing out that min isn't an angular directive. I didn't realize that. I'll try it in firefox and see if it makes a difference

Comment: i have tested my plunkr on chrome and it works fine too. I'd like to see how your extra object is defined and the editable() function

Comment: @valepu Currently the editable() function simply returns true. I edited the question to provide more information. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you are welcome! So, according to this new information i assume that your input is inside an ng-repeat, is that right?

Comment: @valepu That is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109127/discussion-between-jonathan-quinth-and-valepu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just realized that in your onChange function you do this:

`_this.bookingPrice = response.data;`

Which, according to what you wrote in your question, is the object containing the array you iterate on to create your inputs.

When you completely replace the object, `ng-repeat` will create the inputs from scratch. When you have `min` set in your input this will trigger `ng-change` on input creation if the starting input is not valid (angular will set the `ng-model` to undefined in this case), which will change the whole array, which will trigger `ng-repeat` again, recreating inputs with a min attribute, which will trigger `ng-change` again and so on...

Normally ng-repeat generates an hash of the object to track changes on the data it's iterating on, if you completely replace it then it will think you deleted the old object and put in a new one (even though they have the same data), by using `track by extra.id` will tell ng-repeat that even though you replaced the object, they actually didn't change (they still have the same .id) and won't recreate the objects from scratch but, this is a fix but it's probably a good practice to just replace the values of the current array.

I have managed to recreate your issue in this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/XyEyGTvuYKyz1GGmWjuP?p=preview

if you remove the line:

```
ctrl.objects = [{quantity: 0, price: 0, booked: true}, {quantity: 0, price: 0, booked: true}];
```

it will work again

Comment: Same conclusion as me, but worded better and you explained why min causes the problem. Thank you and accepted.Why does min cause ng-change to be called on creation?

Comment: min triggers HTML5 validation on the field and angular will set invalid fields to undefined, if the starting values are correct it won't trigger ng-change

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not quite sure why the problem only occurred with the min attribute on the field, but by adding "track by extra.id" to the ng-repeat that wrapped the input field, I solved the problem. I guess when the "extra" object, on which the model was a property, changed, angular regenerated the input field, triggering ng-change. By tracking by an unchanging id, angular doesn't need to regenerate the input field since the id remains the same, thus not triggering ng-change.

I'll accept this as my answer, but if anyone can explain why it worked without min, I will happily accept their answer instead.

Comment: Wait, i have just noticed one thing. _this.bookingPrice = response.data; is _this.bookingPrice the same object that contains the array where the inputs are?

Comment: @valepu Yes, it is